Date Picker Offsets Values by Two and Doesn't Loop Correctly
I'm working on a custom date picker for a web application that uses the Jalali calendar. However, I'm encountering a couple of issues:
**
my main problem is Value Offset: When I select a number in the picker (e.g., 12), the value displayed in the input box is consistently two less than what I selected (e.g., 10). This happens across all selections (e.g., selecting 10 displays 8, and so on).**
Looping Feature: I want the picker to loop seamlessly, so when a user scrolls beyond the last item, it should wrap back to the first item (and vice versa). However, this behavior isn't currently implemented.
Additionally, the picker needs to correctly handle the Jalali calendar, where months 1 to 6 have 31 days, and months 7 to 12 have 30 days (with the last month possibly having 29 or 30 days depending on the leap year).
I've tried adjusting the index calculations and ensuring the selected index matches the displayed value, but I'm still encountering these issues. Any advice on how to fix these problems would be greatly appreciated.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Persian Date Picker Modal</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jalaali-js/dist/jalaali.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .open-modal-button {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 20px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .persiandatepickermodal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
      .modal-content {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 90%;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .close-modal-button {
        background-color: #dc3545;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .picker {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .picker-columns {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .picker-column {
        width: 80px;
        height: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .picker-column ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        transform: translateZ(0);
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
      }
      .picker-column li {
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .highlight {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      .ok-button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      input {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="open-modal-button">Select Date</button>
    <input type="text" id="selectedDate" readonly />

    <div class="persiandatepickermodal" id="datePickerModal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="picker">
          <div class="picker-columns">
            <div class="picker-column" id="year"></div>
            <div class="picker-column" id="month"></div>
            <div class="picker-column" id="day"></div>
          </div>
          <button class="ok-button">OK</button>
        </div>
        <button class="close-modal-button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Get today's Jalali date using jalaali-js
      const today = jalaali.toJalaali(new Date());

      // Modal Control
      const openModalButton = document.querySelector(".open-modal-button");
      const closeModalButton = document.querySelector(".close-modal-button");
      const modal = document.getElementById("datePickerModal");

      openModalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.style.display = "flex";
      });

      closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      });

      window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (event.target === modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      });

      // Date Picker
      class IosSelector {
        constructor(options) {
          this.el = document.querySelector(options.el);
          this.source = options.source;
          this.selectedIndex = options.selectedIndex || 0;
          this.itemHeight = 30;
          this._init();
        }

        _init() {
          this.el.innerHTML = `<ul>${this.source
            .map((item, index) => `<li data-index="${index}">${item.text}</li>`)
            .join("")}</ul><div class="highlight"></div>`;
          this.list = this.el.querySelector("ul");
          this.items = this.el.querySelectorAll("li");
          this.list.style.transform = `translateY(${
            -this.selectedIndex * this.itemHeight
          }px)`;
          this._attachEvents();
        }

        _attachEvents() {
          let startY = 0,
            scrollStart = 0,
            isDragging = false;

          const onMouseDown = (e) => {
            startY = e.clientY;
            scrollStart =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            this.list.style.transition = "none";
            isDragging = true;
          };

          const onMouseMove = (e) => {
            if (!isDragging) return;
            let moveY = e.clientY - startY;
            this.list.style.transform = `translateY(${scrollStart + moveY}px)`;
          };

          const onMouseUp = () => {
            if (!isDragging) return;
            isDragging = false;
            let finalScroll =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            let selectedIndex = Math.round(-finalScroll / this.itemHeight);
            selectedIndex = Math.max(
              0,
              Math.min(selectedIndex, this.source.length - 1)
            );
            this.select(selectedIndex);
          };

          const onWheel = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let scrollAmount = e.deltaY;
            let currentScroll =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            this.list.style.transition = "none";
            this.list.style.transform = `translateY(${
              currentScroll - scrollAmount
            }px)`;
            let finalScroll =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            let selectedIndex = Math.round(-finalScroll / this.itemHeight);
            selectedIndex = Math.max(
              0,
              Math.min(selectedIndex, this.source.length - 1)
            );
            this.select(selectedIndex);
          };

          this.el.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
          document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
          this.el.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);

          this.el.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
            startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
            scrollStart =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            this.list.style.transition = "none";
          });

          this.el.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
            let moveY = e.touches[0].clientY - startY;
            this.list.style.transform = `translateY(${scrollStart + moveY}px)`;
          });

          this.el.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
            let finalScroll =
              parseFloat(
                this.list.style.transform.replace("translateY(", "")
              ) || 0;
            let selectedIndex = Math.round(-finalScroll / this.itemHeight);
            selectedIndex = Math.max(
              0,
              Math.min(selectedIndex, this.source.length - 1)
            );
            this.select(selectedIndex);
          });
        }

        select(index) {
          this.selectedIndex = index;
          this.list.style.transition = "transform 0.3s ease-out";
          this.list.style.transform = `translateY(${
            -index * this.itemHeight
          }px)`;
        }

        getValue() {
          return this.source[this.selectedIndex].value;
        }
      }

      const getRange = (start, end) =>
        Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => ({
          value: start + i,
          text: start + i,
        }));
      const getDays = (year, month) => {
        const daysInMonth = jalaali.jalaaliMonthLength(year, month);
        return getRange(1, daysInMonth);
      };

      let yearSelector = new IosSelector({
        el: "#year",
        source: getRange(1300, 1500),
        selectedIndex: today.jy - 1300,
      });
      let monthSelector = new IosSelector({
        el: "#month",
        source: getRange(1, 12),
        selectedIndex: today.jm - 1,
      });
      let daySelector = new IosSelector({
        el: "#day",
        source: getDays(today.jy, today.jm),
        selectedIndex: today.jd - 1,
      });

      document.querySelector(".ok-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let selectedYear = parseInt(yearSelector.getValue());
        let selectedMonth = parseInt(monthSelector.getValue());
        let selectedDay = parseInt(daySelector.getValue());

        // Ensure correct values are selected
        const correctDate = (date) => {
          return date < 10 ? `0${date}` : date;
        };

        // Set the selected date in the input box
        document.getElementById(
          "selectedDate"
        ).value = `${selectedYear}-${correctDate(selectedMonth)}-${correctDate(
          selectedDay
        )}`;
        modal.style.display = "none"; // Close modal on OK
      });

      // Update the day selector when year or month changes
      const updateDaySelector = () => {
        const yearValue = parseInt(yearSelector.getValue());
        const monthValue = parseInt(monthSelector.getValue());
        const daysInMonth = getDays(yearValue, monthValue);

        daySelector = new IosSelector({
          el: "#day",
          source: daysInMonth,
          selectedIndex: Math.min(
            daySelector.selectedIndex,
            daysInMonth.length - 1
          ),
        });
      };

      yearSelector.el.addEventListener("mouseup", updateDaySelector);
      monthSelector.el.addEventListener("mouseup", updateDaySelector);
      yearSelector.el.addEventListener("touchend", updateDaySelector);
      monthSelector.el.addEventListener("touchend", updateDaySelector);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

What I Tried:
I attempted to resolve the value offset issue by adjusting the index calculations within the picker. Specifically, I ensured that the selectedIndex corresponds directly to the displayed value, assuming the problem might be due to an incorrect mapping between the selected index and the actual value shown in the input box. I also implemented the looping feature by adding logic to handle when the user scrolls beyond the last item, expecting it to wrap back to the first item and vice versa. Furthermore, I tried to correctly adjust the days for each month according to the Jalali calendar, ensuring months 1 to 6 have 31 days, and months 7 to 12 have 30 days.
What I Expected:
I expected that by making these adjustments, the selected value in the picker would accurately reflect in the input box without any offset (e.g., selecting 12 would display 12, not 10). Additionally, I anticipated that the looping feature would work smoothly, allowing the picker to wrap around when the user scrolls past the first or last item. Lastly, I expected the date picker to correctly handle the varying number of days in each month according to the Jalali calendar.

There's a lot of code here, and very little debugging information.  You also appear to be asking multiple questions.  Please focus on one specific issue you are trying to resolve and narrow the code to a [mcve] which demonstrates that issue.  If you're not familiar with using a debugger then now is a great time to start.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?
